# Ember-auth currentUser

Tags: authentication, ember.js

So I've been following the tutorial at https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo to hook up an ember frontend with a rails backend for authentication purposes. I'm to the point where I can authenticate by submitting a form, and that's great! However now I'm finding I want to do a few things with the current user's information.

Right now, I can successfully sign in and when signed in present a button to sign out. However I'd like to do something like `"You are signed in as {{currentUser.username}}. Sign Out"`

I saw on ember-auth issue #11 they apparently at one point implemented something like this:

https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/issues/11

However, after sign in, my authview shows "You are signed in as. Sign Out"

I suspect the user may not be loaded into the application right now. I understand that I could simply query the database for the current user in the controller, however I view this functionality as something application wide that should be available. Is there a best practice here or should I just implement something myself?

Auth Setup

```
App.Auth = Em.Auth.create
  signInEndPoint: '/users/sign_in'
  signOutEndPoint: '/users/sign_out'
  tokenKey: 'auth_token'
  tokenIdKey: 'user_id'
  userModel: 'App.User'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a user model and does ember-auth know about it?

```
App.Auth = Ember.Auth.create
  # stuff...
  userModel: 'App.User'
```

Comment: Yes, I added my Auth.create block up above.

Comment: userModel has to be a string, not an object, as in your example. Also, does your API allow to /users/:id to get user data? Does `App.User.find(YOUR_ID)` work in console?

Comment: Yes. After converting that to a string, I can get the email by doing `App.Auth.get('user').get('email')` in the console, however trying to embed this in handlebars gives a coffeescript parse error

Comment: @DVG the handlebars equivalent is `App.Auth.user.email`. In general, `get()` calls are replaced by `.` in hbs, e.g. `App.get('foo')` (js) = `App.foo` (hbs).

Answer (score 1):

After reading the docs you mentioned above, the correct way to get access to the `currentUser` object in your templates should be:

```
"You are signed in as {{App.Auth.currentUser.email}}. Sign Out"
```

and not only `{{currentUser.username}}`. I used `App.Auth.currentUser.email` since I haven't seen any `username` property on the `Auth.currentUser` object, but bear with me if there is indeed one then you can use it of course.

Hope it helps.